# Why does Python's None value not seem to be triggering my conditionals?

Tags: python, null, qgis, pyqgis

I have a Python script running inside QGIS. It looks like this:

```
class Ranker(object):
    @staticmethod
    def haversine(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):
        """
        Calculate the great circle distance between two points 
        on the earth (specified in decimal degrees)
        """
        # convert decimal degrees to radians 
        lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(math.radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])
        # haversine formula 
        dlon = lon2 - lon1 
        dlat = lat2 - lat1 
        a = math.sin(dlat/2)**2 + math.cos(lat1) * math.cos(lat2) * math.sin(dlon/2)**2
        c = 2 * math.asin(math.sqrt(a)) 
        km = 6367 * c
        return km

    @staticmethod
    def calculateDistance(featureProperty, layerEntrances):
        if featureProperty.geometry() is None:
            print("Null property geometry! Returning -1!")
            return -1
        shortestDistance = 1000
        featuresEntrances = layerEntrances.getFeatures()
        for featureEntrance in featuresEntrances:
            if featureEntrance.geometry() is None:
                print("Null entrance geometry! Skipping!")
                continue
            latEntrance = featureEntrance.geometry().centroid().asPoint().y()
            lonEntrance = featureEntrance.geometry().centroid().asPoint().x()
            latProperty = featureProperty.geometry().centroid().asPoint().y()
            lonProperty = featureProperty.geometry().centroid().asPoint().x()
            currentDistance = Ranker.haversine(lonEntrance, latEntrance, lonProperty, latProperty)
            if currentDistance < shortestDistance:
                shortestDistance = currentDistance
        return shortestDistance

    @staticmethod
    def importAndAnalyze(rowLimit = 3):
        layerProperties = iface.addVectorLayer("/Users/patrick/Downloads/DOR_Parcel/DOR_Parcel.shp", "Philly_City_Parcels", "ogr")
        if not layerProperties:
            print("layerProperties failed to load!")
        layerEntrances = iface.addVectorLayer("/Users/patrick/Downloads/Stations/philly-rail-stations-merged.shp", "Rail_Stations", "ogr")
        if not layerEntrances:
            print("layerEntrances failed to load!")
        features = layerProperties.getFeatures()
        counter = 0
        featuresSelected = []
        Path('/Users/patrick/Desktop/philly-property-rankings.csv').touch()
        with open('/Users/patrick/Desktop/philly-property-rankings.csv', 'a') as csvFile:
            csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
            csvWriter.writerow(['Address STD', 'Lat','Lon', 'Distance'])
            for feature in features:
                if counter < rowLimit:
                    csvWriter.writerow([feature['ADDR_STD'], feature.geometry().centroid().asPoint().y(),feature.geometry().centroid().asPoint().x(), Ranker.calculateDistance(feature, layerEntrances)])
                    if counter % 100 == 0:
                        csvFile.flush()
                else:
                    break
                counter += 1
            csvFile.flush()

Ranker.importAndAnalyze(10000000)
```

The problem is that after the script handles about 57,000 rows of data, it spits out this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 72, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 64, in importAndAnalyze
ValueError: Null geometry cannot be converted to a point.
```

I do not understand how this error is being reached. Shouldn't my two conditionals that reference the `None` value be enough to skip any null geography values?

Full disclosure: I'm not normally a Python guy. Please be kind if I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Have you seen these: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/325226/solving-null-geometry-error-during-distance-matrix-operation and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/276783/batch-removing-null-geometries

Comment: Which line is line 64?

Comment: I would debug and log/print the value of `feature` and `feature.geometry()` as a start